# Split string and get all after first ocurrence - c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a collection I want to transform into a dictionary. Here's the code:

```
myCollection.ToDictionary(item => item.Split('=')[0], item => item.Split('=')[1]);
```

Being the collection something like:

```
{"a=312d","b=dw234","c=wqdqw3=3")
```

The problem comes at the third object. As you can see, it has a second equal inside of it. This one, and all the character after it, are also part of the value (in the dictionary it should be `c:wqdqw3=3`). But, as you can imagine, I'm getting something like this in my dictionary `a:312d, b:dw234, c:wqdqw3`.

How could you change it so that the value of the dictionary was, for each element of the collection, everything that comes after the first '='?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IndexOf()` and `Substring()` should help here

```
string[] input = { "a=312d", "b=dw234", "c=wqdqw3=3" };
var result = input.ToDictionary(x => x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf('=')), 
                                x => x.Substring(x.IndexOf('=') + 1));
```